# add maven dependency with target java build of 1.6 or multiple

Tags: java, maven

I just want to state this as simple as possible,

I am using [RestExpress](https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress) in my application now, but I am having a big problem with running this into my server.

The problem is that my server runs on OPenJDK 6, but the class build of maven-dependency of RestExpress is 1.7. Is it possible to build the source files as java1.6 or is it possible to have 1.6 and 1.7 build same time?

UPDATE: Im still new to maven dependency build. Im so frustrated right now. its been 3 days

`JRE not compatible with project .class file compatibility: 1.7` 
this is my pressing issue when running the code using 1.6

my `pom.xml`

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

seems like i cant post an image , i need to get at least 10 rep, uploading fail.

After setting up compiler and run it as java 1.6

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/restexpress/serialization/SerializationProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

thanks

Comment: Compile and install `RestExpress` manually with java version 1.6

Comment: Your goal is to compile with 1.7 compatibility.  Your pom.xml syntax is correct, it sounds like it's working.  INSTEAD ... it sounds like you've got a 1.6 JRE ... and you're trying to run 1.7 class files with it.  SUGGESTION: Make sure you don't have any dependencies on any .jar's built with JDK 1.7.

Comment: @dieend I already had done that before and its just the same. any ideas why?

Comment: @FoggyDay how do i know that jar files depends on jdk1.7?

Comment: @Dave Have you edited RestExpress `pom.xml` when compiling it?

Comment: @dieend yes i did, is it wrong?

Comment: @Dave edited it and changed the java version to 1.6? and it still doesn't work? Make sure in your project you are using your custom RestExpress library instead of using library downloaded from maven repository.

Comment: @dieend yes ive tried that before too, and now i tried it again, and the error will be like `view-my-edit` that. 

hmm ill try customizing RestExpress library though.

Comment: @dieend wow, its running now, never thought i missed `RestExpress-Common` by using custom then build it as 1.6, thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

try compile RestExpress in jdk1.6,

modify the pom.xml in that project

```
...
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.6</source>
           <target>1.6</target>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Comment: @Dave I mean you need modify the pom.xml in your custom RestExpress project.